# Bring a *Interruptible slept* process to foreground in current console

Tags: unix, process

One of my process is at *Interruptible sleep* state. Note I ran the process from a different tty. That tty died and currently the process is orphan.

```
ps ax | grep sync-d[b]                                                                                                                                                                     
31809 ?        S      0:00 sync-db upgrade
```

The sate `S` means `Interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)`. How can I send it an event to complete on the *current tty*?

I have already sent `CONT` signal. But it does't seem to respond.

```
kill -CONT 31809
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you.. [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr.git)

Make no mistake, the amount of hackery required to do this is fairly significant - so don't be  surprised if it doesn't work.